# SELECT 'EXIST' or 'NotExist' as a Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL,

```
SELECT SKU FROM Products WHERE SKU IN
(
   'SKU1',
   'SKU2',
   'SKU3',
   'SKU4',
   ......
   ......
   ......

   'SKUN',
)
```

What I need to Select is

```
 SKU    Exist
 ----------
 SKU1    Exist
 SKU2    NotExist
 SKU3    NotExist
 ................
 ................
 ................
 SKUN    NotExist
```

Comment: DO you mean SKU NotExists in Products table ?

Comment: Don't you love stack overflow? Three answers in 5 mins. @user960567, you should definitely vote the ones that work and mark one as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SKU,
    case when p.SKU is null then 'notExists' else 'exists' end [exists?]
FROM (VALUES
   ('SKU1'),
   ('SKU2'),
   ('SKU3'),
   ('SKU4'),
   ......
   ......
   ......

   ('SKUN')
) SKU(SKU)
left outer join Products p on p.SKU = SKU.SKU
```

Comment: Getting Error.. I am using sql server

Comment: I edited my answer, added inside brackets within values

Comment: also deleted comma after last value

Comment: try now, my fault, did not test this, should work now

Comment: Thanks it works but I need OUTER APPLY with Top 1 Because Left Join was returning multiple rows.

Answer (score 5):

```
WITH SKUs AS (
    SELECT SKU
    FROM (VALUES ('SKU1'),('SKU2'),...) AS T(SKU)
)
SELECT SKUs.SKU
      ,CASE WHEN Products.SKU IS NULL THEN 'NotExists' ELSE 'Exists' END
FROM SKUs
     LEFT JOIN Products
         ON Products.SKU = SKUs.SKU
```

Comment: I don't need all products. I need to check only in SKUs

Comment: @user960567, swapped join so it now lists only SKUs